# How to fix "Cannot find module" error and "Error: ReferenceError: Element is not defined" in protractor?

Tags: automated-testing, protractor, jasmine, nodejs

I have created a test project using page object model. When I run, it creates "Cannot find module" error. I have tried several answers but didn't work.
Here is my code

**Config.js**

```
exports.config = 
{
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
//specs: ['spec.js']
specs: ['./testSpec/**/*.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 12000
},
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
}
};
```

**login.po.js**

```
var loginPageLocator = function()
{
var userName = Element(by.model('vm.username'));
var password = Element(by.model('vm.password'));
var signInButtonText = Element(by.buttonText('Sign in'));

this.get = function()
{
    browser.get('http://20.150.10.160/login');

};

this.typeUserName = function(userName)
{
    this.userName.sendKeys(userName);

};

this.typePassword = function(password)
{
    this.password.sendKeys(password);

};

this.clickSignIn = function()
{
    this.signInButtonText.click();

};

};
module.exports = new loginPageLocator();
```

**LoginTest.js**

```
var logins = require('./../pageObjects/login.po.js');

describe('login to the system',function()
{
it('login as a dealer',function()
{
    var loginPage = new logins();
    loginPage.typeUserName('test');
    loginPage.typePassword('222');
    loginPage.clickSignIn();

});

});
```

Here is the folder structure
[image: folder structure]

Package.json
[image: package.json]

Comment: Please ensure npm, protractor version. Thanks!

Comment: @Rohan I have define protractor and jasmine versions in package.json file

Answer (score 1):

In your LoginTest.js , you have given incorrect reference of page object. change it to:

```
var logins = require('../../pageObjects/login.po.js');
```

and then you do not need to create a page object, instead you should directly use the object that you have created earlier like below

```
logins.typeUserName('test');
```

update your conf.js file, a sample is below:

```
    exports.config = {
        directConnect: true,
        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome'
        },
        framework: 'jasmine',
        baseUrl: "http://url.com",
        specs: ['./*_specs.js'],

        onPrepare: function() {
            browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //create a global variable like below
global.variableName = "hello";
        }
}
```

Comment: still it gives the same error. If I imported the package/module correctly it should show methods inside it right? But I don't get suggestions

Comment: Please copy your LoginTest.js under testSpec folder and check.

Comment: path you mentioned works. Now I can access methods. New error appeared "Error: ReferenceError: Element is not defined"

Comment: Browser doesnt navigate to login page

Comment: That's because you haven't called the get method in your test script. call the get method in your it block of LoginTest.js

Comment: Yes I tried calling the method. Nothing changed. I tried defining the url to the side insided loginTest page itself. But still has the problem. Could you check the config file please? I think there is a problem in the config file

Comment: Yes, you haven't mentioned the browser Name anywhere, here is a sample conf.js file for you to work on chrome browser added in the answer.

Comment: I can't see a link, could you update it in your answer? I think it will be useful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94581/discussion-between-pankaj-dubey-and-joe).

Answer (score 0):

Check this, briefly explained here, and you can fix it https://youtu.be/idJHHxA02l8

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why the linked video answers the user's question. Please also indicate that the video is on your channel or you risk your answer being deleted as spam.

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved when I corrected the module name to match exactly with the names of folders and files.
It is case sensitive in Linux systems but not in Windows